# What spirit goes best with lasagna?

Tags: spirits, pairing

My mom's favorite dinner is lasagna with salad, garlic bread, and cheese cake. I make this for her every twice a year; her birthday and Mother's day. What spirit goes best with this dinner?

Answer (score 2):

Not a spirit, but I would serve red wine. In particular a Barbera d'Alba or maybe a Chianti. Red Italian wine seems appropriate and those two are good with pasta in my opinion. It does depend a bit on the kind of lasagna. I'm assuming the standard red tomato sauce kind.

Answer (score 1):

**What spirit goes best with lasagna?**

[Whiskey](https://www.vanillaluxury.sg/magazine/italian-food-and-whisky-pairing-try) or [bourbon](https://www.whiskyadvocate.com/pair-bourbon-with-food/) would be my recommendation for pairing spirits with lasagna. Both go well with pasta dishes and Italian foods in general.

If you prefer beer, please check this out: [What's a good beer to go with lasagna?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/152/whats-a-good-beer-to-go-with-lasagna)

If you desire wine being paired with lasagna the following may be helpful: [10 Wines that Pair Perfectly with Lasagne](https://www.lacucinaitaliana.com/italian-food/italian-dishes/10-wines-you-should-pair-with-lasagna?refresh_ce=)